# ASP.NET Identity password hash not matching plain text password at login

Tags: c#, cryptography, asp.net-identity-2

I'm a little confused at how to present this without "leaking" security information or even whether or not this is a concern for this post.

Please advise in a comment if I should add the problematic hash and password and I'll be more than happy to do that in an edit.

Suffice it to say that a user I've created with ASP.NET Identity as per below can't log in. I've used ILSpy to pick apart the `PasswordSignIn` method and have been able to verify that a user with the supplied username does exist and that the failure appears to be in the verification of the password.

Here's the code with which I'm creating the user:

```
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "user@domain.tdl", Email = "user@domain.tdl" };
var userPassword = "p455W@rd";
var userCheck = userManager.Create(user, userPassword);
```

The user has been created, but when I try to log in with the password, the login fails.

I've actually seeded this user into my database so as to get the actual hash solely for the benefit of this post.

Using the below code which I've taken out of ASP.NET Identity with ILSpy to verify the password, this hash and plain text passwords match.

(You can copy this code directly into dotnetfiddle if you wish).

However, there is a login which I created in exactly the same way who's hash and plain text passwords fail this verification.

Any ideas why the hash would be generated that doesn't resolve back to the original value?

```
public static void Main()
{
    var hashedPassword = "AA29ol/cj3GsR+yEjQWcQufmOvJCy7kZMIiSTMfxCdeXpeeLy2npjVpndBlfRS8kxQ==";
    var password = "p455W@rd";

    var array = Convert.FromBase64String(hashedPassword);
    if (array.Length != 49 || array[0] != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Array length wasn't 49 or the first item in the array wasn't 0");
    }
    var array2 = new byte[16];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 1, array2, 0, 16);
    var array3 = new byte[32];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 17, array3, 0, 32);
    byte[] bytes;
    using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, array2, 1000))
    {
        bytes = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(32);
    }
    var equals = ByteArraysEqual(array3, bytes);

    if (equals)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Arrays equal");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Arrays do not equal");
    }
}

public static bool ByteArraysEqual(byte[] a, byte[] b)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (a == null || b == null || a.Length != b.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }
    bool flag = true;
    for (int i = 0; i <a.Length; i++)
    {
        flag &= (a[i] == b[i]);
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Comment: can you verify that the password arrives at the Rfc2898DeriveBytes call as entered? so... no fancy encoding issue ?